# How to pass data from viewbag to model in CSHTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a hard time passing data to my model using viewbag.

Here is some example to enlighten you:

```
@model UCPBEscheatment.Models.aspnet_Membership
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AnswerForgotPassword";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<em style="font-size:small">@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Forgot Password was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")</em>
<fieldset style="background-color:#f0f0f0">
<legend> Forgot Password </legend>
<br />
 • Second step: <em style="color:Teal"> Answer your secret question</em>
 <br /><br />
<b> Secret Question:</b> @ViewBag.question 
<br /><br />
<b> Secret Answer: </b>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.PasswordAnswer)
<br /><br />        
@{

      INPUT CODE HERE TO PASS A VALUE TO THE MODEL USING VIEWBAG LIKE:

  ex.
      @MODEL.USERID = VIEWBAG.USERID

}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />


</fieldset>


}
```

Comment: my question is how can i pass a value to the MODEL directly 
like my @Model.PasswordAnswer = ViewBag.answer

i wwant to explicitly pass or declare a variable to my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. You can't assign to the model that is being returned in the post. I'd suggest adding the user's id to the form url and using the id on the url to find the user that needs the password secret validated.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("validatepassword","account",new { id = ViewBag.UserID }))
{
     ...
}
```

Or better yet, set the user id on the model and use it from there instead of the ViewBag, but still using it in the url to post back.

Comment: OMG http://stackoverflow.com/users/12950/tvanfossonThank you so much , it really helped me hahaha 
now i can go do my forgot password module